# How do I construct a VARBINARY(MAX) from a byte value with LEN = 1?

Tags: sql-server

Please, observe:

```
DECLARE @b VARBINARY(MAX) = 5
SELECT @b Value, LEN(@b) Length
```

Yields

```
Value       Length
0x00000005  4
```

What I need is a VARBINARY(MAX) instance that equals 5, but has the length of 1.

**Motivation:**

I would like to generate the following sequence of VARBINARY values:

```
0x00
0x80
0x8080
0x808080
0x80808080
0x8080808080
0x808080808080
...
```

With an arbitrary depth given as a parameter. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @Depth INT = 50

;WITH number AS (
    SELECT TOP (@Depth - 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 n
    FROM sys.objects
), mask AS (
    SELECT n, CAST(0 AS VARBINARY(MAX)) mask
    FROM number
    WHERE n = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT mask.n + 1 n, CAST(mask.mask + CAST(0x80 AS VARBINARY) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) mask
    FROM number
    JOIN mask ON number.n = mask.n
)
SELECT n,mask FROM mask
```

And I am almost there, only the result is:

```
n   mask
0   0x00000000
1   0x0000000080
2   0x000000008080
3   0x00000000808080
4   0x0000000080808080
5   0x000000008080808080
6   0x00000000808080808080
7   0x0000000080808080808080
8   0x000000008080808080808080
9   0x00000000808080808080808080
10  0x0000000080808080808080808080
...
```

So, my problem is the length - it is 4 bytes minimum. I need it to start from 1.

**EDIT 1**

Found the answer to my primary problem:

```
DECLARE @Depth INT = 50

;WITH number AS (
    SELECT TOP (@Depth - 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) - 1 n
    FROM sys.objects
), mask AS (
    SELECT n, CAST(0x80 AS VARBINARY(MAX)) mask
    FROM number
    WHERE n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT mask.n + 1 n, CAST(mask.mask + CAST(0x80 AS VARBINARY) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) mask
    FROM number
    JOIN mask ON number.n = mask.n
)
SELECT 0 n,CAST(0 AS VARBINARY(1)) mask
UNION ALL
SELECT n,mask FROM mask
```

But I do not understand why it does not have the same problem as my original solution. Why do the VARBINARY values now have the minimum length of 1 and not 4 as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal `5` is of type `INT`, which is 4 bytes. The literal `0x80`(mind the `0x`!) is of type `BINARY(1)`, which is 1 byte. If you had written

```
DECLARE @b VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x5;
```

You would have achieved the desired result.